# How to know the last page number website in web scrape in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am scraping data from flipkart where I want to scrape all the product's name, price and ratings. So I want to scrape all the required information from all the pages.
There are 11 pages in this link:
https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/mi~brand/pr?sid=tyy%2C4io&otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Mi
So how can I make loop till I reach at end of the pages i.e. till 11th page number.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please edit the question to include what have you tried and what was the specific problem that you encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from itertools import zip_longest


def mxnum():
    r = requests.get(
        "https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/mi~brand/pr?sid=tyy%2C4io&otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Mi")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    for item in soup.findAll("div", {'class': '_2zg3yZ'}):
        mxnum = list(item.strings)[0].split(" ")[-1]
    return int(mxnum) + 1


mxnum = mxnum()


def Parse():
    with requests.Session() as req:
        names = []
        prices = []
        rating = []
        for num in range(1, mxnum):
            print(f"Extracting Page# {num}")
            r = req.get(
                f"https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/mi~brand/pr?sid=tyy%2C4io&otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Mi&page={num}")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            for name in soup.find_all("div", {'class': '_3wU53n'}):
                names.append(name.text)
            for price in soup.find_all("div", {'class': '_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK'}):
                prices.append(price.text[1:])
            for rate in soup.find_all("div", {'class': 'hGSR34'}):
                rating.append(rate.text)
    for a, b, c in zip_longest(names, prices, rating):
        print("Name: {}, Price: {}, Rate: {}".format(a, b, c))


Parse()
```

Comment: Yeah, I made this possible by using for loop from 1 to 11 but here I have to know the last page number manually from website. And I want to make it dynamically identify the last page number.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

The url from page 1 to 11 is defined by:

```
https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/mi~brand/pr?sid=tyy%2C4io&otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Mi&page={n}

    where n is from 1 to 11
```

So you can create a loop where n=1 to 11 and replace n by its current value in the loop.

Comment: Yeah, I made this possible by using for loop from 1 to 11 but here I have to know the last page number manually from website. And I want to make it dynamically identify the last page number.